# Automated Scripting

Tags: command-line, scripts, security

I was wondering if there was a way to set a chain of commands to run without having to type the in individually everytime you want to run it. That way, when I get an computer to secure I can just run a preset series of commands to enable password policies and such. I have all the commands I want to run already. Also is there a way to do an if/then the same way? Like if this program is found on the computer, delete it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is a batch script. It allows you write your commands to a file that you can then run with the terminal.

Additionally, control elements can be used like if / else conditions or case switches.